# Retrieve User Properties from a lookup Column using REST api

Tags: rest, sharepoint, office365

i have a SharePoint list where i hold the list of users i intend to retrieve the pictureurl for each users.

How do i retrieve all the properties of the lookup so i can figure out which properties i need. In my example i know there is a Title and Name property, how can i know what the rest are using Console.log

```
var getsiteContacts = function siteContacts () {

     // execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
             url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Contact')/items?$select=user/Title,user/Name&$expand=user",
             type: "GET",
             headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
             success: function (data) {



             var DataResult = data.d.results;
             //var user = DataResult.userId;
             for (var i = 0; i < DataResult.length; i++) {

                if(DataResult[i].user!=null){
                    var userDetails1 = DataResult[i].user.Name.split('|')[1];
                    var userDetails = DataResult[i].user.Name;


                    //Get the user profile picture for each user
                    console.log(userDetails);
                    console.log(data);

             }
                getProfilePicture(userDetails); 

            }                 


         },
            error: function () {
            //alert("Failed to get details");
        }

    });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the user properties that you can use.

1   Id
2   ContentTypeID
3   ContentType
4   Name
5   Modified
6   Created
7   Account
8   EMail
9   MobileNumber
10  AboutMe
11  SIPAddress
12  IsSiteAdmin
13  Deleted
14  Hidden
15  Picture
16  Department
17  JobTitle
18  LastName
19  FirstName

If you want to display Email Address or First Name or Last Name , You need to construct the URI as below.

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Contact')/items?$select=Users/EMail,Users/FirstName,Users/LastName,Users/EMail&$expand=Users/Id
```